# How to make jar file from eclipse project including library?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to make my project into a jar executable.

That much I can do but I need my external library as well.

How do you specify the location of an external library? Right now I have added it to my eclipse project,but later on I need it to execute my program outside of eclipse on a server.

The Library is the postgres-jdbc driver to connect to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `Fat Jar` or `Runnable Jar` i.e a single jar which will contain all it's dependent jars in it.

If yes, it can be generated in eclipse using **File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable Jar**

Optionally you can specify the `start-class` having the main method.

If you don't want as a `Runnable jar`, you've to add all your dependent jars in classpath before starting your application.

`java -cp <add all lib> -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Comment: so you mean that i can include my jdbc jar library inside my jar?

Comment: please see my updated answer, 2nd approach is recommended

Comment: I am exporting as a runnable file already, but I dont know how to add my libraries,when i run it asks for libraries

Comment: Did you select `Package required libraries into generated JAR` option while generating runnable jar in eclipse?

Comment: do you've your dependent libraries in classpath ?

Comment: i did it again and it worked,dont know why the mistake happened but thanks